# Block Wowza Live repeater connection in FMS

Tags: flash, flash-media-server, fms3

Some unauthorized users are connected and fetch video from my flash media server using "Wowza Live repeater configuration ". Is there any way to block it in FMS configuration level ?.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found alternate way to block this using iptables.